# Python finding elements in scraping

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, tags, find

How can I get id name and all attributes for collection_item?

I tried (source is page source):

```
all = source.find("id").get_text()
all_category = all.find_all(class_="collection-item")
for All in all_category:
    CATEGORY_name = All. find (class_='name').get_text()
```

[code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5rPZd.png)

But it doesn't work. I have an error:'NoneType' object has no attribute 'find'
I printed Menu and I see all id in page source

Comment: Can you post URL of the site? If not, can you edit your question and put the HTML source code as text, not as image?